# Angular changes not reflected on server live code

Tags: angular, ng-build, ng

[image]

My changes above in screenshot. Just changed the text to `Download PDF` before it was something else.

Replaced the folder here with the complied code [image]

Used this command to compile: `ng build --base-href=/parent/ --configuration=production`

I have Angular code. I made changes to it and complied with it. It complied successfully with no errors and when I replace the complied folder in server it does not reflect changes.

I tested it out by changing the spelling to make sure I am not making wrong changes or at least the small spelling such as “Ham” to “Han” should reflect as its just text changes but I see no changes.

The process I followed is:

1. Make my changes to the file let’s say parent.html
2. Compile the whole folder that has parent.html which is `parent` folder.
3. It creates `dist` folder and inside `dist` folder it had `parent` folder, so I replace the parent folder in live server because in server we have `parent` folder where I want to make changes, so I replaced it with my parent folder with my changes.

So, what I am doing wrong here or missing something, so it does not reflect changes? I had to change in complied file to reflect the changes which is not best way.

Comment: On Localhost, Did You see the Change??

Comment: Yeah I can see the changes on localhost @JensonMJohn

Comment: Try this Command `ng build --prod --clear-cache`.

Comment: @JensonMJohn I already tried that

Comment: Ok. Unless I see Your Code, Proper Solution will get delayed.

Answer (score 0):

Just look through the dist folder an look for you changes if they are there probably your server caches the files. If not you maybe need to specify the project in the build command.